# Query posts from current year

Tags: posts, categories, query, order, date

I don't quite get why this isn't working. I'm trying to use the following to only show posts from the current year on the front page:

```
<?php query_posts( "&year=$current_year&order=DESC"); ?>
```

Yet it still shows posts from 2012 (they weren't actually made in 2012, but I set the publish date to one of the posts that's showing to Feb of last year)

According to the documentation, that's how I should be doing it. Can anyone shed any light?

Thanks

Comment: Nevermind, I forgot to set the variable:

 <?php $current_year = date('Y');  ?>

/Facepalm

Comment: Here's info on [When should you use WP_Query vs query_posts() vs get_posts()?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts) for anyone who happens by this question.

Answer (score 6):

You just need get current date and add it on data_query in wp_query, Look this:

```
<?php 

$getdate = getdate();
$args = array(
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'year'  => $getdate["year"]
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

?>
```

and then use loop:

```
<?php 

if ( $query->have_posts() ): while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

the_title();
the_content();

endwhile; endif;

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Don't use `query_posts` to modify your queries.** It's a waste of resources and it produces unpredictable results, as it overwrites the original query which happens before the template is loaded.

Use [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) in your theme's `functions.php` instead to alter the query *before* it is sent to the database, and before the template is loaded.

```
function home_page_current_year( $query ){
    if( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() )
        $query->set( 'year', date('Y') );
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'home_page_current_year' );
```